# Git - Undo Overwriting a Branch

Tags: git, version-control, command

Instead of

```
git checkout <mybranchname>
```

I did

```
git checkout -B <mybranchname>
```

which has overridden the branch I wanted to switch to with the branch I was switching from.

Is there a way to undo this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Type `git reflog`. There you should see a checkout of your renamed branch.
Something like:

```
56d04f9 HEAD@{8}: checkout: commit-message of your missing branch
```

The first column is the hash of the commit. So you copy the hash and type `git checkout <hash>`. In the example it would be `git checkout 56d04f9`. This should checkout your missing branch and you can rename it back.

Comment: Nice one. Thank you sir.

Comment: Thank you, you just saved my life. Well, not literally, but almost.